# How do I log an error with ELMAH when catching an error for proper JSON formatting in MVC 3

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, elmah

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 application where I'm making an AJAX call and expecting a JSON result back.  I'm using ELMAH to log errors.  While testing I had an unexpected error.  ELMAH logged the error, but my client side script doesn't because the result is not proper JSON now.  If I handle all errors in the controller to return a proper JSON result, then the error doesn't get logged by ELMAH.  I know I can call ELMAH specifically to log the error, but I rather like that I don't have to do that anywhere else.

Can anyone clarify the 'proper' way to handle this scenario?

for example

```
    try
{
                //service.dosomethingwitherror();
    return new JsonResult { Data = new { result = true, message = "Success." } };
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return new JsonResult { Data = new { result = true, message = "Failed." } };
}
```

Since I'm 'handling' this, ELMAH doesn't log.  If I don't handle this my client won't get JSON...

Answer (score 5):

You can use the ErrorSignal class to log manually. This will perform all configured elmah operations (log, mail, tweet, etc).

```
ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(new NotSupportedException());
```

See http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/DotNetSlackersArticle#Signaling_errors for more information.

If you really don't like adding that code to your controller, you could not catch the exception server side and handle the ajax error event in your javascript.

Comment: thanks for the response.  I have considered as you said, but it seems as though there should be a good mvc way of knowing I need a JSON result and packaging the error for that.  If I can't find a beter answer, I'll do as you suggest.

Comment: You might be able to create a `JsonElmahErrorAttribute` class that inherits `ElmahErrorAttribute` and overwrites the model with `new JsonResult { Data = new { result = true, message = "Failed." } }`.